# Jquery change value of span tag - reference from another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So my html code is:

```
<div class="product-details">
    <div class="availability in-stock">
          Availability: <span>In stock</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to use Jquery to change the span value of "in stock".  I am somewhat new to Javascript and Jquery, so how would I change that span value without it having an id to reference.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$('.in-stock span').html("your new string");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hQqtU/

Comment: I had no idea jsfiddle existed.  Appreciate it!  Now I can fiddle out my simple questions until I get it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
$('.product-details .availability span').text('foo');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/EryVF/

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is either the `text()` or the `html()` like so:

```
$('.availability span').html('This is what you want to change it to');
```

Here is an example: [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/YbGJy/)